# Init array of objects by iron-ajax (link response to caller's element)

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

Let's say I have an array of objects which just have an id:

```
[{id:'1'},{id:'2'},{id:'3'}]
```

and I want to fill them with data from some service one by one using iron-ajax:

```
<iron-ajax id="initObjectByIdService"
           handle-as="json"
           on-response="_handleResponse"></iron-ajax>
...
initObjects: function(){
  for (var i =0; i < arr.lenght; i++){
    this.$.initObjectByIdService.url = <some_url> + '/' + arr[i].id
    this.$.initObjectByIdService.generateRequest();
  }
},
_handleResponse: function(event){
   // How I can link this response event with proper element of an array?
}
```

What could be useful is to pass caller's element index to `on-response` function, something like:

```
...
this.$.initObjectByIdService.onResponse = this._handleResponse(i);
...
```

But it looks strange and wrong and doesn't work... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ES6 solution

You should be able to solve this problem by using the **let** keyword like this:

```
initObjects: function() {
     // using let instead of var
    for (let i =0; i < arr.lenght; i++){
        this.$.initObjectByIdService.url = <some_url> + '/' + arr[i].id
        var request = this.$.initObjectByIdService.generateRequest();
        request.completes.then(function(response) {
            // your i variable should be available in this block
        });
    }
},
```

## Another solution

A solution without the need of the **let** keyword could look like this:

```
initObjects: function() {
     // using let instead of var
    for (var i =0; i < arr.lenght; i++){
        this.$.initObjectByIdService.url = <some_url> + '/' + arr[i].id
        var request = this.$.initObjectByIdService.generateRequest();
        request.completes.then(this._handleResponse(i));
    }
},    

_handleResponse: function(i) {
   return function(response) {
     // i variable should be normally visible in this scope
   };   
}
```

In both cases you should also remove the **on-response** attribute from the **iron-ajax** component.